# How to create matrix from data in a text file MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-table

I have a text file called epsi_20_20. In this file there is a large table with data. I would like to be able to create in MATLAB a matrix containing only the values of the last six columns. How can I do it? I tried with load but it does not seem to work.

```
##ASTER 13.06.00 CONCEPT table2 CALCULE LE 02/12/2019 A 10:08:31 DE TYPE          
#TABLE_SDASTER                                                                   
INTITULE         NOEUD    RESU     NOM_CHAM         NUME_ORDRE   INST         ABSC_CURV    COOR_X       COOR_Y       COOR_Z       EPXX         EPYY         EPZZ         EPXY         EPXZ         EPYZ        
node1            N2549    finalmoy EPSI_ELNO                   1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.00000E+01  3.50000E+01  0.00000E+00  6.26777E-04 -1.78490E-04  0.00000E+00 -1.63122E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
node2            N2556    finalmoy EPSI_ELNO                   1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.00000E+01  5.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  6.26779E-04 -1.78490E-04  0.00000E+00  1.63087E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
node3            N2561    finalmoy EPSI_ELNO                   1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  9.00000E+01  3.50000E+01  0.00000E+00  6.06777E-04 -1.82032E-04  0.00000E+00  3.99969E-08  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
node4            N2570    finalmoy EPSI_ELNO                   1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  9.00000E+01  5.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  6.06777E-04 -1.82032E-04  0.00000E+00 -3.99968E-08  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the code you tried? This is called a [mcve]. Be sure to indicate the desired input, output, and any errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file using `readmatrix`. First, you can specify some import options with [`delimitedTextImportOptions`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.text.delimitedtextimportoptions.html). For your particular example, it is sufficient to specify that the data starts at line 4, and that you want to join delimiters (spaces).

```
opts = delimitedTextImportOptions('DataLines',4, 'Delimiter', ' ', 'ConsecutiveDelimitersRule', 'join')
A = readmatrix('yourfile.txt', opts) % results in cell array, due to mixed numbers and strings
```

Then you can select the last 6 columns of the cell array `A`, and convert the strings to numbers:

```
data_of_interest = str2double(A(:,end-5:end));
```